# Font-identification exceptions: identifiers don't work with slight distortions

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, font-identification

About the closing vote at this question:

[What is the font used in Sega ads during the 90's?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/111110/120647)

It's clear that the OP didn't put all the things he tried before. But, to avoid immediate closing votes in the future, there are some things to verify, at least visually. I add two samples of identifications from the web owner of this font [Extension RR ExtraBold](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/redrooster/extension-rr/), mifont.com.

- This identification is made with an original image, match the font at first:

[image: What the font match]

- This is made with the same image horizontally scaled, no match:

[image]

Should this exception appear somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think we should be making it more complicated when already few follow our guidelines.

Comment: Ok, in such a case  the question is here to show that this exception exists.

Answer (score 5):

The main reason why we require using automatic identifiers is to avoid trivial questions where all we do is to feed the asker’s image into an automatic identifier.

If the image needs to be rescaled or otherwise modified in a manner that is not blatantly obvious, this is not the case. Being able to spot (and sometimes apply) these modifications is where the answerer can shine with expertise and what makes for a good font-identification answer.